# GUI for editing "Open with" menu

Tags: nautilus, gnome-shell, 18.10, .desktop

When you manually install programs and you want to add them to the "Open With" list in the context menu, you usually have to create edit multiple `.desktop` files I think is rather cumbersome as there are a lot of ways to make mistakes. Is there a a program with a GUI to do that for you? (Or maybe even a native way?)

I have found `alacarte` but that only makes your programs available for adding to the launcher.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the "hard" part (viz. creating a `.desktop` launcher in `~/.local/share/applications/`) using the GUI tool `alacarte` and then make a slight modification to the `.desktop` file manually.

Note that a `.desktop` launcher created with `alcarte` is found in `~/.local/share/applications/` and usually with a name of the form `alacarte-made*.desktop`. You need to open such a file with a text editor and check/modify a couple of things:

1. There should be a `NoDisplay=true` line. This hides the application from your applications menu. So add (or modify) a `NoDisplay=true` line.
2. Make sure there is a proper [field code](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) (`%f` / `%F` / `%u` / `%U`) at the end of your `Exec=` line. This means the line should look like

   ```
   Exec=/path/to/the/program %f
   ```

   or something similar, *not* simply

   ```
   Exec=/path/to/the/program
   ```